# DISTINCT on one value from a group selects

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have following sql query

```
select devices_device.id , devices_device.code, sss.id as "site_id", sss.name as "site_name"
from devices_device
inner join st_site_site sss on devices_device.site_id = sss.id
where devices_device.deleted = false
order by devices_device.id, devices_device.start_date
```

I now get a list of device id's. Some of them are the same. I want to do a distinct so I only keep the first record for every device (and due to order by on start_date that would be the most recent device record for that device)

How do I do this? If I do

```
select distinct devices_device.id , devices_device.code, sss.id as "site_id", sss.name as "site_name"
from devices_device
inner join st_site_site sss on devices_device.site_id = sss.id
where devices_device.deleted = false
order by devices_device.id, devices_device.start_date
```

nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to identify the row you want. Then filtering out the other ones is easy.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select
    d.id, d.start_date, d.code, 
    s.id as "site_id", s.name as "site_name", 
    row_number() over(partition by d.id order by start_date desc) as rn
  from devices_device d
  inner join st_site_site s on d.site_id = s.id
  where d.deleted = false
) x
where rn = 1
order by id, start_date
```

In this query the `ROW_NUMBER()` value will be `1` for the latest row in each device group. That's how the filtering at the end removes all other rows greater than `1`.

**NOTE**: In case there are collisions (two rows with the same recent start_date) this query will always return a *single* [though random] row between them.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Gonna need to learn what it all means but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a GROUP BY. Something like:

```
select distinct devices_device.id , devices_device.code, sss.id as "site_id", 
sss.name as "site_name"
from devices_device
inner join st_site_site sss on devices_device.site_id = sss.id
where devices_device.deleted = false
group by devices_device.id
order by devices_device.start_date
```

Comment: 'should probably ' - you aren't sure?

Answer (score 0):

You could test for the min start date

```
drop table if exists devices_device,st_site_site;
create table devices_device(id int,code int,site_id int,start_date date,deleted int);
create table st_site_site(id int,name varchar(10));
insert into devices_device values(1,10,1,'2020-10-01',0),(1,20,1,'2020-09-01',0);
insert into st_site_site values(1,'aaa');

select devices_device.id , devices_device.code, sss.id as "site_id", sss.name as "site_name"
from devices_device
inner join st_site_site sss on devices_device.site_id = sss.id
where devices_device.deleted = false and
        devices_device.start_date = (select min(d1.start_date) from devices_device d1 where d1.id = devices_device.id)
order by devices_device.id;

+------+------+---------+-----------+
| id   | code | site_id | site_name |
+------+------+---------+-----------+
|    1 |   20 |       1 | aaa       |
+------+------+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: "ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE"